# RADIUS log not visible in Console under macOS Sierra

Tags: osx-server, macos, logs, console

We only have Radiusconfig log viewable in Console, but the Radiuslog is not visible. Although it exists under /private/var/log/radius. In older operating system versions the RADIUS log was greyed out in Console, but you could activate it and view it, in macOS Sierra it does not show up in Console.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the log info that was being redirected into custom logs (via asl) is now just going into the system log. The best way to find out about an individual service is to use the `log` command (`man log`). The radius server is radiusd, so I would expect to see useful info from:

`log stream --predicate  '(process == "radiusd")' -info`